# How can i sort using an external method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i'm making an Items class and people write reviews where the reviews contain rating and the in the item model , I had written a defined method called 'average_rating' which calculates the average rating for the items by collecting all the ratings in the reviews corresponding to this item.
now i want to sort the items by using this function yet I get that it's an undefined function.
Item Model:

```
  class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
        belongs_to :category
      def average_rating
        if self.reviews.size > 0
           sprintf('%.2f', self.reviews.average(:rating)) 
        else
            'undefined'
        end
    end
     def self.search(query)
        where("name like ?", "%#{query}%") 
      end
      def self.top(query)
       text= Category.where(name: query).first
      where("category_id like ?", "%#{text.id}%")
    end
    end
```

Item view:

```
<%  @items=@items.sort_by{|x,y| x.average_rating <=> y.average_rating } %>
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>
    <%= link_to item.name, item %>
</h4>
   <ul>
    <li><%= item.description %></li>
    <li> <%= item.average_rating %> </li>
</ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Error:
undefined method `average_rating' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Where in your controller do you define `@items`?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because some of your `item` is `nil`. You can do something like this to remove the blank/nil values first, and then sort them:

```
local_items = @items.compact.sort_by{|x,y| x.average_rating <=> y.average_rating }
```

or,

```
local_items = @items.reject { |c| c.blank? }.sort_by{|x,y| x.average_rating <=> y.average_rating }
```

#### Update

Try to rename the local variable to `local_items` in your view and then loop through that:

```
local_items = @items.compact.sort_by{|x,y| x.average_rating <=> y.average_rating }
```

Then:

```
<% local_items.each do |item| %>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>
    <%= link_to item.name, item %>
</h4>
   <ul>
    <li><%= item.description %></li>
    <li> <%= item.average_rating %> </li>
</ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: the error remains.
I checked my db and there's no null maybe because i don't have an average_rating column in my db .

Comment: How about? `@items = @items.compact.sort_by{|x,y| x.average_rating <=> y.average_rating }`

Comment: undefined method `compact'

Comment: Make sure you defined `@items` in your corresponding controller.

Comment: I did define it and that's why the page loads fine without using the sort .

Comment: Try to rename the local variable and then loop through using the local items name: `local_items = @items.compact.sort_by{|x,y| x.average_rating <=> y.average_rating } Then, `local_items.each ....`
`

Answer (score 0):

You get this type of error when the object your calling your method *on* is `nil`.

I guess there is a `nil` in your `@items` list - you can get a copy of an array with all `nil` removed by calling `@items.compact`